# Remove Lines in Multiple Text Files that Begin with a Certain Word

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, grep, csh

I have hundreds of text files in one directory. For all files, I want to delete all the lines that begin with HETATM. I would need a csh or bash code.

I would think you would use grep, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed` like this:

```
sed -i -e '/^HETATM/d' *.txt
```

to process all files in place.

`-i` means "in place".

`-e` means to execute the command that follows.

/^HETATM/ means "find lines starting with HETATM", and the following `d` means "delete".

Make a backup first!

If you really want to do it with `grep`, you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.txt
do
   grep -v "^HETATM" "%f" > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp "$f"
done
```

It makes a temporary file of the output from `grep` (in file `$$.tmp`) and only overwrites your original file if the command executes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-v` option of `grep` to get all the lines that do not match:

```
grep -v '^HETATM' input.txt > output.txt
```